# filter table by drilling down json objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am having trouble filtering a table by drilling down objects (by object´s object).

I have the object "match", which contains the object "team" which has the value name.

I would like to sort it like this:

```
<tr class="active" ng-repeat="match in matches | filter: {team1.name: filter, team2.name: filter}">
```

but cant find a way to do that.

here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>teams</th>
        <th>time</th> 
        <th>field</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="active" ng-repeat="match in matches | filter: {id: filter}">
        <td>{{match.team.name}} vs {{match.team2.name}}</td>
        <td>{{match.date}}</td>
        <td>{{match.field.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my objects are here:

```
match = {
     id: int
     team1: obj
     team2: obj
     time:  date
     field: obj
};
team= {
     id: int
     name:string
};
field= {
     id:int
     name: string
     location: string
};
```

can i configure the filter to do this, or do i have to do this in code?

Comment: use custom filter in controller for this.

Comment: @SSH thanks i will look in to it.. do you hava any good examples I can look  to?

Comment: your information is little. please display more about your object.